# how to remove duplicate words in a string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

consider I have this string

```
a='flexray_datain_flexray_sensors'
```

and I want to process this string to get

```
a='flexray_datain_sensors'
```

And the thing is this can be for any repeated words and not just **flexray** in matlab. If I already know what the word is then it's easy

I tried:

```
 parts = textscan(bypname , '%s', 'delimiter', '_');
    parts = parts{:};
```

and then processing this cell(parts) using unique or something and removing the repeated words. But I need a better answer .

Comment: How do you define a word? Is a word any characters separated by a hyphen (`_`)?

Comment: not necessarily it can also be ebct2_o_ebct1 and this can be a complete word @kkuilla

Comment: try use `strsplit` and `unique`?

Comment: @Dan no it doesn't work

Comment: @ArunKumar "no it doesn't work" is a useless comment. You have to explain what you tried and why it didn't work. Did you get an error? Did you get the wrong result? If so what was wrong about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
strjoin(unique(strsplit(a,'_'),'stable'),'_')
```

Comment: perfect. This is what I was looking for . Much more elegant than my way